# How to send a URL string / web request from a button pressed in an IOS application

Tags: ios, web-services, url, button

I would like to remote control my Sonos System as well as my home automation system with my old IOS devices I do not use anymore. I have in multiple rooms multiple devices installed, so I'd like to develop per room a separate screen, which allows me to execute certain functions.

For instance in my garden I'd like to turn on the radio, change volume, change radio station switch on the light, dim the light.

I would like to have one screen showing me several buttons as well as slider.

Button1 labeled "mute" shall mute the Sonos system by calling a URL:

```
  http://myphpwebserver/pagetocontrolsonos.php?mute=true
```

Button2 labeled "louder" shall mute the Sonos system by calling a URL:

```
  http://myphpwebserver/pagetocontrolsonos.php?louder
```

and so on ....

The php page does not provide any feedback, but only calls the Sonos.
The PHP page is already developed and works fine. I just want to have native buttons in a native iPhone app.

In addition calling the Sonos I'd like to call my Home-Automation System to switch an dim ma light.

Slider1 labeled "light" shall call a URL from Home-Automation Server based on slider setting.

In case slider is set to the middle it shall call:

```
 http://myhomeautomationserver/lamp.php?dim=50% - while 50% is the slider setting.
```

What do I need to perform to call a URL from a button or a slider?
Can someone help?

Comment: Seems like it might be a whole lot easier to add a web page to your php server that has buttons that calls these URLs for you.

Comment: I'd like to keep the app open, which is not possible with a browser AFAIK

Comment: Don't really know what you mean, but, you do know that there is a Sonos App in the App Store?

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSURLConnection to send URL requests. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/) for an introduction on how to do so.

Comment: Thanks, that does not solve my slider issue, but I'll try it first of all with the buttons!

Comment: Well you'd have to send asynchronous requests to the server where you append the slider value to the request URL. I would probably recommend a UIStepper, since a slider's value can change way too often before your request has been completed. A UIStepper allows you to cancel and do another request if the values change fast.